# Не могу понять для чего поле в классе модели

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2

Есть в книге пример:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; } // страна игрока
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Негде не описано зачем в сущностях `Country` & `Team` добавили поля `public List<Player> Players { get; set; }`, поясните пожалуйста. Просто у меня и без него работает все нормально, а это поле только `null` всегда. Какой толк с него?

Мой код:

```
[MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
    public class Category
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
        public Images Image { get; set; }
    }

    [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
    public class Images
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
        public string ImageType { get; set; }
        public int ImageSize { get; set; }
        [MySqlCharset("utf-8")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }
```

результат `return Ok(_productContext.categories.Include(x => x.Image));`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `myDatabaseContext.Teams.Where(team=>team.Id == 10).Include(team=>team.Players).ToArray()`?

Comment: Небольшое замечание - поле, это `public string Prop;`, у вас же свойства, они имеют get и set (`public string Prop {get; set;}`).

Comment: вы ответ в вопрос добавили или вам ещё что то не ясно? Какие то вопросы остались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, так называемые, **навигационные свойства** - через них реализуются **отношения** (**один-ко-многим**, **один-к-одному**, вот это вот всё), почему оно у вас `null` - это отдельный разговор.

Обычно надо писать что-то подобное:

```
myDatabaseContext.Teams.Where(team=>team.Id == 10).Include(team=>team.Players).ToArray()
```

Тогда список `Players` будет заполнен.